# Learning the Introspection API (used by FxCop)

Tags: visual-studio-2008, fxcop

Microsoft's FxCop tool uses the introspection API. This introspection API could be used to develop new code analysis tools. But the introspection api is not documented well. Additionally, I was not able to figure out any blogs which explains this API in breadth and depth of it. The knowledge gained by understanding the API can also be used for writing custom FxCop rules.

Does anybody knows about any blog or resources which explains the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one: http://www.binarycoder.net/fxcop/html/index.html